# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I am facing the issue while I am adding the .so file in my project, from the other ans, I have tried with different solutions but not any solution help me out.

**case: 1** I had tried to put my .so in src/main/jniLibs and in the gradle file I had added below lines, but getting the same error.

```
 android {
     sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []
}
```

**case:2** I had added cpp folder with native-lib.cpp and in gradle added below code:

```
defaultConfig {
 ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
  }
   }
```

**case:3** I had created new fresh project with c/c++ support and add a .so file under cpp folder and in the gradle added below code:

```
defaultConfig {
  externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-std=c++11"

        }
    }
}
```

[My project architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLkn9.png)

**error code:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ai.kitt.snowboy.demo, PID: 15175
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ai.kitt.snowboy.demo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libsnowboy-detect-android.so" 
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
 at ai.kitt.snowboy.audio.RecordingThread.<clinit>(RecordingThread.java:20)
 at ai.kitt.snowboy.Demo.onCreate(Demo.java:49)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)  
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

I am using android studio 3.0.1, gradle: 3.0.1

Comment: To which library you are getting this error and which architecture your getting this error, this information helps to answer.

Comment: I have edited my question, I had added the image. I am trying to add the .so file in armeabi and armeabi-v7a.

Comment: If you are copying manually then it is not right, the library binary file for  each architecture is different.

Comment: Please upload the whole `UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed` log. There are many info in the end message indicated what happened actually.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you, can you please explain a bit.

Comment: As far as I can see, there was no `x86` so. It must fail if you try to run app on an emulator.

Comment: @KhyatiChitroda just post all stacks print around `UnsatisfiedLinkError`

Comment: Where does this libsnowboy-detect-android come from? If you only have armeabi and armeabi-v7a versions of it, then why have you added x86 and mips in your abiFilters?

Comment: @Michael I have added those at that time, but that was not worked for me so I have removed.

Comment: @sakiM I have edited in post please check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try add this in `build.gradle`:

```
sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
```

or add following into `android` block:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
    }
}
```

Gradle may have problem when read default jniLibs path, just make it implicit.

`sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs` not work because it defines `jni source`, like cpp source files folder.

Exception stacks *nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]* shows that system didn't detect your lib at all. To verify it, exact your apk to see whether there is a `/lib` folder and your `*.so`.

Comment: I have tried by adding this, still same error facing.

Comment: @KhyatiChitroda Notice that this is `jniLibs.srcDirs`, nor `jni.srcDirs`. Have you unzip your apk to see whether there are so files in `/lib`?

Comment: @KhyatiChitroda It may be in a wrong path because sourceSet starts on module folder... Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Comment: You could accept the answer and vote up if it solves your problem really. :)

Comment: almost correct. There should be a subfolder under `jniLibs` named after architecture such as arm64-v8a, which is used as `ndk {abiFilters}` entry in `build.gradle` of app module.

Answer (score 0):

Or make your main library a SHARED library.

```
add_library(libname SHARED
    //files.cpp
)
```