# Android can not added apllication to google store APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices but they only have 32-bit native code

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-build

When I try put application in google store I see this :

This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code. I have only  32 - bit native code I do this on build gradle :

From August 1, 2019 all releases must be compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.

Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app.

```
ndk {
            moduleName "***"
                abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86_64", "mips",'arm64-v8a'
        }



        task nativeLibsToJar(type: Jar, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
            destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
            baseName 'native-libs'
            from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
            into 'lib/'
        }

        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
        }
        splits {
            abi {
                include  "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
            }
        }

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
                // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
                def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "arm64-v8a":2]
                def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                    output.versionCodeOverride =
                            versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
                }
            }
        }
```

But I can not add apk on google store

[image]

edit

[image]

edit

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

edit
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: Don't use APK to upload to play store, use AAB

Comment: @Hooman                  abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86_64", "mips",'arm64-v8a'
, 'x64'  this ?

Comment: @MichaelStoddart but steal I can not uplaoud apk

Comment: So upload an AAB instead!

Answer (score -1):

Here all what you need about supporting 64-bit architectures

https://inneka.com/programming/android/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio-2/

check your project structure and include libraries like below..

```
 project/
├──libs/
|  └── *.jar       <-- if your library has jar files, they go here
├──src/
   └── main/
       ├── AndroidManifest.xml
       ├── java/
       └── jniLibs/ 
           ├── arm64-v8a/                       <-- ARM 64bit
           │   └── yourlib.so
           ├── armeabi-v7a/                     <-- ARM 32bit
           │   └── yourlib.so
           └── x86/                             <-- Intel 32bit
               └── yourlib.so
```

Comment: I do this :        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
but steal I can not put apk on google store . What I should change ?

Comment: Basically check your project structure and include libraries for 64bit

Comment: Dreamer so I have to delete all I do in build.gradle ?

Comment: What is the structure of your project ? where is the place of **.so files? check them if you not see folders of 64 bit create folders for 64bit and copy manually **. so files ..and build your app

Comment: I post screen which structure is a correct ? and I delete from build.gradle ndk ababiFilters  ect

Comment: /armeabi/libfoo.so -------
/armeabi-v7a/libfoo.so -------
/arm64-v8a/libfoo.so---------
/x86/libfoo.so --------
/x86_64/libfoo.so

Comment: You need to read this if above solution didnt work ... https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html

Comment: Now I get this error :     java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/***/lib/arm64/libpackage.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206122/discussion-between-kiki-kala2-and-dreamer).

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48678598/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed