# Getting error : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libtriangulation.so" not found in Android java

Tags: java, android, unsatisfiedlinkerror, .so

I am running an old Android project from year 2019 on the Android Studio Version Electric Eel.

I have imported an existing module in that project which is using a **.so library**. When I'm executing the below line, I'm getting this error : **Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libtriangulation.so" not found**

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("triangulation");
        
    }
```

This is my Project structure :
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKtiJ.png)

The **3dViewer** is the external module which I have imported in the project. You can see that the **libtriangulation.so** file is already included in the **jniLibs** folder.

Any help is appreciated. I'm stuck in this error for past 4days.

**Tried all the solutions given in the below links, but none of it worked for me :**

[java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076641/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed-library-not-found)

[java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48678598/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed)

https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/issues/587

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I have the same or very similar looking problem now.

Comment: No, didnot get any solution for this particular problem. But I created a fresh project and transferred the old project codes to the new one. This solved the issue for me