# Android [Google ML Kit] Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed

Tags: android, google-mlkit

We are using a Google ML kit for QR code scan. It works for most of the devices but application crashes for a few devices (*Samsung Galaxy A05, Samsung Galaxy Note10 Lite*). When a user tries to scan the QR code from the Galley or Camera application crashes.

Platform: `Android`

SDK: `com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber`

SDK Version: `17.2.0`

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0 Runtime.java:1003
java.lang.System.loadLibrary System.java:1661
com.google.android.libraries.barhopper.BarhopperV3.<init>
com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.bundled.internal.zzb.zzc
com.google.android.gms.internal.mlkit_vision_barcode_bundled.zzbk.zza
com.google.android.gms.internal.mlkit_vision_barcode_bundled.zzb.onTransact
android.os.Binder.transact Binder.java:1165
com.google.android.gms.internal.mlkit_vision_barcode.zza.zzc
com.google.android.gms.internal.mlkit_vision_barcode.zzsw.zze
com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.internal.zzl.zza
com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.internal.zzi.zze
com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.internal.zzi.run
com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.MobileVisionBase.zza
com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.zza.call
com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.ModelResource.zza
com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzn.run
com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzt.run
com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zze
com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzc
com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzk.run
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644
com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzd
com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzi.run
java.lang.Thread.run Thread.java:1012
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0 Runtime.java, line 1082
```

Note: We are scanning the QR code from the Gallery as well as capturing it from the camera.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48678598/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed